# Why does this code throw an exception when trying to read in a struct's instance using a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

We are currently learning address and pointer logic in C and this was given as classwork earlier. Every time I run this code I get an exception thrown after the first scanf_s line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student
{
    char name[20];
    char id[10];
    float GPA;
};

void readStudent(struct Student* ptr) 
{
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s\n", &ptr->name);

    printf("Enter id: ");
    scanf("%s\n", &ptr->id);

    printf("Enter GPA: ");
    scanf("%f\n", &ptr->GPA);
}
void printStudent(struct Student* ptr)
{
    printf("Name:%s\n", ptr->name);
    printf("ID:%s\n", ptr->id);
    printf("GPA:%f\n", ptr->GPA);
}

int main() 
{
    struct Student* ptr, student1;
    ptr = &student1;
    readStudent(ptr);
    printStudent(ptr);
}
```

Update: I changed it to scan_f instead of scanf_s, but now it only takes the input of the first scan_f and not the others.

[image: It only takes the name but not the ID]

Comment: Do you know the difference between `scanf` and `scanf_s`?

Comment: @user2357112 I do not, but when I don't use it, visual studio gives me a warning/error and says scanf_s is safer.

Comment: It's safer, but the arguments are different. You can't just replace `scanf` with `scanf_s`.

Comment: @Barmar I switched it, but now it does not let me enter the second scan_f statement. I am sorry about this question as I am sure it is quite easy, but I am struggling with C syntax for some reason.

Comment: You don't use `&` for arrays. `&ptr->name` should just be `ptr->name`.

Comment: maybe you are struggling because you did not read the documentation. Try [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170). Also consider that these functions are scanners, hence their names, and where written to consume tabular data, not get input from the keyboard. You MUST consume the `\n` that ended each call. You MUST test the returned value: read nothing is not an error for this functions

Answer (score 2):

I tested out your code, and actually did not get a segmentation fault.  But when the code was compiled, the compiler provided some clues with the warnings it listed.

```
    main.c|15|warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]|
```

What that basically is saying is that you are referencing a "pointer to a pointer" where a string is being inputted, which in your testing is probably trying to store your input into an undefined area of memory.

Also, within the "scanf" functions, you would not want to include the "\n" (newline character), just a proper format reference (e.g. "%s").

With that, following is some refactored code.

```
void readStudent(struct Student* ptr)
{
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->name);

    printf("Enter id: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->id);

    printf("Enter GPA: ");
    scanf("%f", &ptr->GPA);             /* Here, the ampersand is proper */
}
```

Also, just to have good etiquette, since the "main" function is expected to return and integer value, it is a good idea to do so when finishing the function.

```
int main()
{
    struct Student* ptr, student1;
    ptr = &student1;
    readStudent(ptr);
    printStudent(ptr);

    return 0;       /* Always a good idea to include when the function is expecting to output an integer value */
}
```

With those bits of refactoring, following was a test run of the program.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/StudentInfo/bin/Release$ ./StudentInfo 
Enter name: Craig
Enter id: 10-888-444
Enter GPA: 3.33
Name:Craig
ID:10-888-444
GPA:3.330000
```

So, to summarize, be cognizant of how to reference pointers within a "scanf" call, especially for strings which are character arrays.

Comment: Thank you! How do we know when the ampersand is required for the scan function?

Comment: I will defer to tutorial sites for a proper answer to that.  FYI, here is one of the initial sites I found, "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanf-in-c".  That should provide some insight.

Comment: "Also, just to have good etiquette, since the "main" function is expected to return and integer value, it is a good idea to do so when finishing the function." This isn't necessary in main() specifically, since some 25 years back. It doesn't cause any harm but it is essentially just clutter.